# Performance drop in R data.table with high number of columns

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I am new to data.table, so maybe I am using it wrong. But could it be possible, that a massive performance drop occurs with a high number of columns?
E.g.

```
> dim(prob.2.gene)
[1] 482421     34

> key(prob.2.gene)
[1] "Symbol"


> dim(pat.met.normal.DT)
[1]     49 390953

> key(pat.met.normal.DT)
[1] "rn"


> system.time(prob.2.gene[J("ELMO2")])
       User      System verstrichen 
      0.016       0.000       0.015 

> system.time(pat.met.normal.DT[J("TCGA-CH-5763-01")])
       User      System verstrichen 
    148.230       0.298     149.424
```

Maybe one of you has a hint.

With best regards,

Mario

Comment: Yes.  It is entirely possible. Just a note, you'll get a lot more help if you post some of the data so we don't have to guess what is looks like.

Comment: The binary search would've been very fast. Most of that time would be just *subset* on those ~391k columns. Try with `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)` to see the time spent on the binary search (join). The rest is just on subset, which to my knowledge is unavoidable.

Comment: Yepp, `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)` uncovered the performance lags. It's the subset. I transposed my matrix. Thank you